# ReactJS - mapped array not updating after ajax

Tags: reactjs

I've got a simple component that renders a table. The rows are mapped like this:

```
render () {
    return (
        {this.state.data.map(function(row, i){
            return <Row row={row} key={i}/>
        }.bind(this))}
    )
}
```

The state is initialized in the constructor:

```
this.state = {
    data: props.hasOwnProperty('data') ? props.data : [],
    route: props.hasOwnProperty('route') ? props.route : null
}
```

The data can be initialized in the DOM, or after, the route is passed to the container and bound correctly. In this case, I 'm doing it after in the `componentDidMount` method:

```
componentDidMount () {
    axios.get(this.state.route)
        .then(function(resp){
            this.setStateParametersFromAjax(resp);
        }.bind(this))
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        })
}
```

The `setStateParametersFromAjax(resp)` method is defined here:

```
this.setState({
    data: resp.data.data,
});
```

This all works flawlessly on DOM load. However, there are buttons that will perform subsequent requests later on. These requests perform the same `axios` call.

The problem is, that even though the `state` is updated (verified by adding a callback as the 2nd argument to the `setState` method and logging `this.state`), the DOM does not update.

What do I need to do to make it so that the DOM updates with this new data as well?

*Edit*

I had simplified the code a bit, there is a method called `fetch()` that accepts an argument of `params` that defines the ajax call:

```
fetch (params) {
    if(typeof params != "object") {
        params = {};
    }
    axios.get(this.state.route, {
            params
        }).then(function(resp) {
            this.setStateParametersFromAjax(resp);
        }.bind(this))
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
        })
}
```

The `componentDidMount()` method calls this on load:

```
componentDidmMount () {
    this.fetch();
}
```

When a button is clicked later, this calls a function that calls the fetch method with parameters:

```
<li className="page-item" onClick={this.getNextPage.bind(this)}>
```

Where the function is defined:

```
getNextPage (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.fetch({
        arg: val
    });
}
```

Comment: You should put your get ajax call in a function and call that after new data is posted.

Comment: @fungusanthrax See my edits, perhaps I wasn't clear initially.

Comment: I believe the event parameter may be undefined, which probably should throw an error somehow, which may be the reason the DOM isn't updating. When you call this.getNextPage.bind(this), it doesn't pass an event parameter. So you should use in the onClick onClick={function(event) {event.preventDefault; ...}. Try that...

Comment: @fungusanthrax It does work correctly. Using `.bind(this)` differs from passing `this.getPreviousPage(this)`. The first is contextual and the second is an argument and will invoke the function immediately on page load. I know that the fetch etc is all working correctly because, as stated in my question, when I do `this.setState({ params...}, function() { console.log(this.state) })`. it does show that all of the data is updated. Further, all of the other data returned is updated on the page, just not the rows on the table. Although the `this.state` does contain the updated rows.

Comment: maybe use a unique `key` value other than index. https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318#.6vgmhxett

Comment: @JiangYD I do, I just omitted it here because it doesn't have anything to do with the problem. The issue is that even though the server responds with the proper data, when I use `this.setState({ data: resp.data.data})`, the state **is** updated, but the DOM is not.

Comment: I think you not understand me. React determines which DOM node need be updated by lot's of things, not only the state, but also how you write the JSX https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html

Comment: @JiangYD I totally misunderstood you. Maybe this is the issue - I'm going to check this out and I'll report back. Thanks!

Comment: @JiangYD Dude. You are the man. I should've read the reconciliation documentation better. This makes way more sense. Thanks a ton! If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a unique key value other than index. Even the state is updated, react may not update DOM if the key not changed.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html